# Any person is contagious, or Any people are contagious

Tags: some-any

Which is more correct?  If both are correct, do they mean the same thing?  Is there a shift in emphasis?

```
I wonder if any person is contagious
I wonder if any people are contagious
```

Comment: Both are grammatical and mean the same thing, though neither is as idiomatic as "I wonder if anyone is contagious" (or "any of them" or "any of the people").

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I should have used "any snakes are poisonous" for a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both.

She is contagious.  and/or They are contagious.

The shift in emphasis occurs separately.  In the one case it is implied that a single person holds influence over something.  In the other it is implied that many people have the same influence.